# generate pagination with ngTables

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ngtable

Well I'm trying to generate a [ngtable](http://ng-table.com/#/), but this is not generate the pagination correct, I'm following the examples but the pagination does not work for me, What is the problem:

```
function usersMainCtrl($scope, NgTableParams, usersFactory)
{
    var tableData = []

    //Table configuration
    $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
        page: 1, // show first page
        count: 5 // count per page
    },{
        //total:tableData.length,
        filterDelay: 300,
        //Returns the data for rendering
        getData : function(params) {
            return usersFactory.getUsers(params.url()).then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(params);
                params.total(response.data.length);
                return response.data;

            });
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will start by saying that I am a bit of a newbie with ngTable myself, but I believe the issue is something to do with the fact that you are getting data from the server side.

I too was trying to get this to work, and was following the ngTables example here:
http://ng-table.com/#/intro/demo-real-world

What isn't made clear in this example though, is that the pagination is being handled by the server too (in fact, the majority of the examples of this site are really bad, as they are using imported code not listed).

How I've been getting around that is by explicitly setting the returned data in the NgTableParams, and then ngTable handles the pagination itself. Here is an example of a table I have which brings back some stock records from a rest API set up as an Angular Factory - this is my controller which is simplistic, but working:

```
myApp.controller('stockListController', [
'$scope', '$timeout', '$q', '$http', 'stockList', 'NgTableParams', 
function ($scope, $timeout, $q, $http, stockList, NgTableParams) {
    $scope.loading = true;

   function initTable() {
       stockList.getAll({ url: "localhost:52457"})
            .$promise.then(function (response) {
                $scope.data = response;
                $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                    count: 2 // size of page
                }, {
                    dataset: response
                });
                $scope.loading = false;
            }, function (response) {
                alert('Rejected');
            });
    }

    initTable();
}
```

]);

This may not be useful in your scenario (if there is a load of data, I imagine the load could potentially be slow) but hopefully it may give you something to work with, or another angle to look at.